# Improving the performance of a python code aimed at finding numbers within certain intervals with large dataset

Tags: python, performance

I have a dictionary as follows(here for simplicity, only one key is given):

```
intervals={'Sca1': [[1428, 1876, 0.0126525], [1876, 1883, 0.0126525], [1883, 1939, 0.0126525], [1939, 1956, 0.0126525], [1956, 2032, 0.0126525], [2154, 3067, 0.0126525], [3067, 3438, 0.0126525], [3438, 3575, 0.0126525], [4301, 4610, 0.0126525], [4610, 4694, 0.0126525], [4694, 5163, 0.0126525], [5163, 5164, 0.0126525], [5164, 5530, 0.013], [5530, 5858, 0.0127005]]}
```

and a list as follows:

```
snplist = [1786, 2463, 2907, 3068, 3086, 3398, 5468, 5531, 5564, 5580]
```

I would like to check for each value in snplist, whether it is in an interval between the first two values of a sublist of the dictionary's value. For example, `1786` is between `1428` and `1878` of `[1428, 1876, 0.0126525]`. If so, then print the index of that sublist, in this case, `0`, the element from the snplist, in this case `1786`, and the third value in the sublist, in this case, `0.0126525`. I wrote the following code:

```
output=[]
for element in snplist:
    for key, value in intervals.items():
        for left, right, rho in value:
            if left <= element <= right:
                output.append([value.index([left, right, rho]), element, rho])
print 'output', output, '\n'
```

output is:

```
[[0, 1786, 0.0126525], [5, 2463, 0.0126525], [5, 2907, 0.0126525], [6, 3068, 0.0126525], [6, 3086, 0.0126525], [6, 3398, 0.0126525], [12, 5468, 0.013], [13, 5531, 0.0127005], [13, 5564, 0.0127005], [13, 5580, 0.0127005]]
```

This code works well for this small dataset but when I use it with my very large dataset, it becomes extremely slow. I used list comprehension as follows:

```
output = [[value.index([left, right, rho]), element, rho]
    for element in snplist 
    for key, value in intervals.items()
    for left, right, rho in value
    if left <= element <= right]
```

But this was no improvement. Is there any suggestion on how I could increase the speed of my code by reducing the number of for loops for example? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you could transform your dict values into numpy arrays there is some speedup:

data:

```
intervals_numpy = {'Sca1': np.array([[1428, 1876, 0.0126525], [1876, 1883, 0.0126525], [1883, 1939, 0.0126525], [1939, 1956, 0.0126525], [1956, 2032, 0.0126525], [2154, 3067, 0.0126525], [3067, 3438, 0.0126525], [3438, 3575, 0.0126525], [4301, 4610, 0.0126525], [4610, 4694, 0.0126525], [4694, 5163, 0.0126525], [5163, 5164, 0.0126525], [5164, 5530, 0.013], [5530, 5858, 0.0127005]])}

intervals_list = {'Sca1': [[1428, 1876, 0.0126525], [1876, 1883, 0.0126525], [1883, 1939, 0.0126525], [1939, 1956, 0.0126525], [1956, 2032, 0.0126525], [2154, 3067, 0.0126525], [3067, 3438, 0.0126525], [3438, 3575, 0.0126525], [4301, 4610, 0.0126525], [4610, 4694, 0.0126525], [4694, 5163, 0.0126525], [5163, 5164, 0.0126525], [5164, 5530, 0.013], [5530, 5858, 0.0127005]]}

snplist = [1786, 2463, 2907, 3068, 3086, 3398, 5468, 5531, 5564, 5580]
```

Functions:

```
def foo(intervals, snplist):
    output=[]
    for n in snplist:
        for key, value in intervals.items():
            for idx in np.where( np.logical_and(value[:,0] < n, n < value[:,1]) )[0]:
                output.append([idx, n, value[idx][2]])
    return output

def bar(intervals, snplist):
    output=[]
    for element in snplist:
        for key, value in intervals.items():
            for left, right, rho in value:
                if left <= element <= right:
                    output.append([value.index([left, right, rho]), element, rho])
    return output
```

In this setup `bar` is about three times as fast compared to `foo` for me:

```
%timeit bar(intervals_list, snplist)
The slowest run took 6.22 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop

%timeit foo(intervals_numpy, snplist)
The slowest run took 5.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.8 µs per loop
```

But numpy pays off for large arrays! In this setup it is about 500x faster:

```
intervals_numpy['Sca1'] = np.repeat(intervals_numpy['Sca1'], 1000, axis=0)
intervals_list['Sca1'] = intervals_numpy['Sca1'].tolist()

%timeit bar(intervals_list, snplist)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.05 s per loop

%timeit foo(intervals_numpy, snplist)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.04 ms per loop
```

Most of this huge speed difference is because of your index lookup, see the answer of Martin Evans. But still the numpy version is a bit faster for me.

Comment: Both single and multiple matches. By the way, you meant calling foo is much faster than bar, not vice verse, is that right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment -- I edited and clarified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. There is a small improvement to be had by removing the index lookup by using `enumerate`.
2. The use of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) should also help with the iterating.
3. You do not currently make use of the `key`, so `.values()` could be used.

These would give you the following:

```
for element, value in product(intervals.values(), snplist):
    for index, (left, right, rho) in enumerate(value):
        if left <= element <= right:
            output.append([index, element, rho])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try changing the order of iteration.

If `snplist` is the smallest and have say 10 elements like in your example and `intervals` have for example 10<sup>6</sup> keys with 10 elements each, and for simplicity lets say that iterating over anything take time 1 unit of time (ut) for each 1000 element then in this scenery we have that all your time go iterating over the `intervals` with 1000ut.

Then with yours current way

```
for element in snplist:
    for key, value in intervals.items():
        ...
```

it take 10000ut to do the job.

Change it to

```
for key, value in intervals.items():
    for element in snplist:
        ...
```

so only take 1000ut, and as you don't care about the key at all in your code that should not be a problem.

In general try to iterate over the big one first and then over the smallest one.